# Reading only the first level of JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset that contains a 2 level JSON String. Here is an example of what my json looks like:

```
 "{"field1":"AAA","field2":{"subField1":"000","subField2":"111"},"value":100.0}"
```

When I parse it using the `read().json()` function of Spark datasets, I get the following result:

```
 field1, field2, value 
 AAA, [000,111], 100.0
```

I want to find a way to setup my Dataset Reader so it only parses the first level of my JSON, giving my the following result :

```
field1, field2, value 
AAA, {"subField1":"000","subField2":"111"}, 100.0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily achieve this by defining the schema explicitly

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("field1",StringType,true),StructField("field2",StringType,true),StructField("value",StringType,true)))
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("path.json")
df.show(false)
```

[image]